# How can I set big array size in pascal?

Tags: arrays, size, pascal

I need to create an array in pascal with an enormous size, is such thing possible ?
I know the size number, I mean it's not `n` or unknown, it's just a really really big number:

2 ^ 255

Can I do that or not ? and if not is there any other way I can make something like that happen ?
Thanks in advance

---

Update:
The peoblem I'm trying to solve is, by giving a number between 1 to 255 (including 1 & 255), I need to print all Gray Code with length of that number, for example:
giving n=2 the program should print:
00, 01, 11, 10

since I have the max number of size that I can enter I assumed I'd make an array with the max number, the thing is maybe I can solve this with recursion, but I;m very new to pascal so I don't know how can I do that (at least not yet)

here's what I meant:
`type arr = array[1..255,1..MAXINT] of integer;`

hints and tips can be very helpful <3

Comment: Why not just create a dynamic array?

Comment: Erm that number is bigger than you seem to think ...

Comment: @Hey24sheep how do I do that ? I am actually new to pascal, can you show me please ?

Comment: @AlexK. Yea, I know. I don't think there is any data type that can handle that big number. Is there?

Comment: @conantannous dynamic array won't work even. It needs setLength before working.

Comment: An array of 2^255 bytes is would need ~10^64 GB to be stored.  To get help with your question you need to explain exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Hey24sheep Hahaha maybe I solved the problem in an idiot way.. but the solution works, just not for numbers bigger than MAXINT .. Lol

Comment: @conantannous Good to know that.

Comment: @Hey24sheep Updated, if you can take a look at what I'm trying to do XD

Comment: Printing the result on 255 input with 32 lines per page on a 0.1 mm thick paper, would result in a pile with height of 2*10^55 light-years. The observable radius of the universe is only about 45.7*10^9 light-years.

Comment: Afaik most compilers don't allow arrays > 2GB.

Comment: @conantannous I have posted my answer.

Comment: @Marco: Delphi would allow it for 64 bit, but 10^64 GB is 1. far too much for any current PC and 2. it would take thousands (millions?) of years to fill such an array.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, if a computer can calculate each value in 1 nanosec, it would "only" take 1.8*10^60 years.

Comment: @LURD: Oh, then I was a few orders of magnitude off (in the wrong direction <g>). Not trillions, not gazillions, no, b(r)azillions! They would have to restart the universe a few times first. <g>

Comment: The size of RAM (in GB) required for the allocation of the array can't be stored in an `Int64` variable. If we burn this array to DVD disks the stack of these discs will be 2,7*10^10 light years and their mass will be ~558 Earth masses ~ almost 2 Jupiter masses and approximately the mass of all objects of the Solar system except the Sun.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is seems useless to store such a big ammount of data in an array instead of fetching it on demand.

Here are the reasons:

1. The supposed array must be populated programmatically (a human being is unable to populate such an array manually) and this means you definitely have an algorithm for that purpose.
2. How will you allocate 10^64 GB (calculated by @Alex-K) of memory to store all this data?
3. Windows 7/8 Ultimate x64 has a maximum RAM limit of 192 GB and 512 GB respectively (for x32 - 4 GB only).
4. How much time you think it will take to initialize this array and assign values to its memebers?

Conclusion:

1. Why not to use a `function Foo(const bt:byte; const it: cardinal): integer;` intended to populate the array for the purpose of fetching the necessary values? You will fetch the data from something like `Foo(100 ,32000)` instead of `MyArray[100, 32000]`.
2. If you have some exclusions (values that are different from those calculated by `Foo` changed at runtime by your user) you can ever store them in an `array of TMyRec` (or TList) where `TMyRec = record Val: integer; Bt: byte; It: cardinal; end;`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not proficient in pascal but here is something I have written. It takes a numeric input and converts it in binary then into gray code.

This is the best I could do as again Pascal is not my main lang of work. :)

```
Uses Math;

var
a,b,d,e,f:integer;
c:array[1..255] of integer;

begin
write('input a decimal number! ');
readln(a);
write('grey code of decimal ',a,' is ');

if a<=1 then write(a) else

repeat
 b:=b+1;
 d:=a div 2;
 c[b]:=a mod 2;
 if d<=1 then
 begin
  b:=b+1;
  c[b]:=d;
 end;
 a:=d;
until d<=1;

for e:=b downto 1 do
begin
 //HERE YOU WOULD NEED TO EDIT AND FIX THIS, I THINK THIS WILL ONLY WORK FOR 
 //1-9
 write(c[e -1] xor 1 shl (c[e]>>1));
end;

readln
end.
```